# Parse the nested json objects

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

Goal is to ready this I have a schema as shown below. How can I parse the nested objects and load it in HIVE table, so far I have this code.
Running Spark version 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91
I need help with this coding, I have attached initial code if anyone can please help.

```
     root
     |-- CustData: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- TimeStamp: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Value_x: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Value_y: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Value_z: double (nullable = true)
     |-- Cust_ID: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Deprt_ID: string (nullable = true)
     |-- EndTime: double (nullable = true)
     |-- EndTimeZone: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Salesd: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- Salesd_Value1: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Salesd_Value2: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Salesd_Value3: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Salesd_Value4: double (nullable = true)
     |-- Cust_RespData: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- TimeStamp: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Cust_RespData_val1: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Cust_RespData_val1: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Cust_RespData_val1: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Cust_RespData_val1: double (nullable = true)
     |-- Cust_RespData_ID: string (nullable = true)
```

```
#!/bin/python2
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
##from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import json

# define context
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

# load sources
jsonFile = "hdfs://loaclhost/data/cust_salesd.json"
sd = spark.read.json(jsonFile)
sd.printSchema()
sdf = sd.select "CustData","Cust_ID","Deprt_ID","DriverID","EndTime","EndTimeZone",explode(col("Salesd").alias("Salesd_ROW")))  
sdf.show()
sdf1 = sdf.select("CustData","Cust_ID","Deprt_ID","DriverID","EndTime","EndTimeZone", "Salesd_ROW.Salesd_Value1", "Salesd_ROW.Salesd_Value2", "Salesd_ROW.Salesd_Value3", "Salesd_ROW.Salesd_Value4")

sdf1.show()   
## how can I load it to HIVE table ??? 
    spark.stop()
```

Comment: is it okay if you get flattened jsons? Meaning all nested objects will be converted to a separate column

Comment: Actually I need to load this flat data to HIVE table, how can I do that?